# Can I limit the displaying of Django's Page not found?

Tags: django

When I develop Django websites, I always develop them on a server that sits on the Internet in order to mirror my production environment (I run macOS locally but my servers are Linux).  During development I also will set `DEBUG = True` for debugging purposes.  The problem is that if I or anyone else who's poking around on my site enters an invalid URLconf string, Django displays the "Page not found (404)" page along with all valid URL patterns, which I feel is a bit of a security risk.  For example, my custom URL for the Django admin site is listed there.  Is there a way to disable the showing of this specific error page when I have DEBUG set to True or perhaps to limit its display to particular IP addresses?

Answer (score -1):

you can override the default 404 view.

Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) to know how to do